# summing in separate using break java scanner

Tags: java, loops, io, switch-statement

I have data in txt :

```
1 
2
3

4
5
6
7
8
```

if I want to sum in separate ex : 1+2+3 result is 6 and 4+5+6...n= 30

Separated list means the list of numbers separated with empty line. For example in above example, numbers `1 2 3` and `4 5 6 7 8` are separated with empty line. I want the sum of first 3 numbers and then next 5 numbers separately.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("patch.txt");
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
   //sum each numbers
}
```

How do I do it? Read data using scanner.

Comment: Sorry I read your question twice and I still don't get what you mean by "sum in separate". You should explicitly mention what input users provided, what output is expected etc.

Comment: you seem to have missed a closing brace on scanner.

Comment: If any of the below answers solves your problem, please accept it. This way the correct answer floats up and you and the answerer are awarded with some reputation that can let you use SO more effectively.

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner (new File("patch.txt")); 
int sum = 0;
while (/* Condition to ensure end of file: sc.hasNextLine or similar */)
{
 String str = sc.nextLine ();  // Read the line
 if(str.isEmpty()) {  // There was no number. You may want to add more checks for example check space only string, dash string etc
   // Print separated sum
   System.out.println ("Sum = " + sum);
   sum = 0; // reset sum
 } else {
   // Update sum
   sum += Integer.parseInt (str);
 }
}
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/pHq1Bv)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner (new File("patch.txt")); 
int sum = 0;
while (sc.HasNextLine ())

{
 //sum each numbers

 String str = sc.nextLine ();
 sum += Integer.parse (str);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below. But If you have a empty line at the end of the file you need not have the print statement outside.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("patch.txt"));
    int sum=0;
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        try{
        sum +=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(sum);
            sum=0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    sc.close();
```

What this does is, it loops through each line, adds to sum when it is an integer. When an exception is thrown at a empty line, the sum is initialized to zero.